# OPENROWSET with no column alias?

Tags: sql-server-2008, openrowset

I'm trying to write a query to select the results of a stored procedure into a temp table. However the stored procedure has been set up so that when it runs its returns 1 result with no alias. (See below)

[image]

obviously I get an error when I try and select the data into a temp table.

> An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO
>   statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look
>   for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed.
>   Change the alias to a valid name.

Is there any way round this as I will be unable to update the procedure to output an alias! Basically Im after a way of doing a

```
SELECT * INTO #tmptable
 FROM OPENROWSET ('SQLNCLI', 'Server=ServerName;Trusted_Connection=yes;','SET FMTONLY OFF EXEC sp_name')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know how many columns you will get back from the `OPENROWSET`, then you can create the temporary table before inserting values; this allows you to give the columns a name.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmptable (Value INT NOT NULL)
INSERT #tmptable
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET ('SQLNCLI','Server=ServerName;Trusted_Connection=yes;','SET FMTONLY OFF EXEC sp_name')
-- DROP TABLE #tmptable
```

If you do not know how many columns you are returning... I do not know that it is possible.